# why my flip animation didnt change to another view?

Tags: iphone, ios5, xcode4.3

This is my code for flip animation, i using 2 views that is viewMain and viewStart

```
- (IBAction)readyBtn:(id)sender {
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
    [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight forView:[self view] cache:YES];
    [[self view] addSubview:viewStart];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}

- (IBAction)startBtn:(id)sender {
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
    [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft forView:[self view] cache:YES];
    [viewStart removeFromSuperview];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

after i run it, my viewMain is flip to the same viewMain, it cant change flip to viewStart. how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

```
(IBAction)readyBtn:(id)sender {
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
    [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight forView:viewMain cache:YES];
    viewStart.frame = viewMain.bounds;
    [viewMain addSubview:viewStart];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
```

Comment: but why my viewStart show up after my viewMain finish flip? its weird